# Ng-template to bootstrap popover inside svg

Tags: angular, svg, ngx-bootstrap, bootstrap-popover

I'm developing a web application using Angular 5 with Ngx-Bootstrap and I'm having a trouble in the template inside a SVG tag.

I'm doing a loop in a svg group (g tag). Inside G I have some foreignObjects and I want to use bootstrap popover for each foreignObject when mouse is on it, but I need make binding inside the popovers, and template needs data from loop.

```
<g *ngFor='let textBox of textBoxes'>
    <foreignObject [id]='textBox.name' [attr.x]='textBox.topLeftNode.x' [attr.y]='textBox.topLeftNode.y'
        [attr.width]='getWidth(textBox)' [attr.height]='getHeight(textBox)' [popover]='commentsTemplate' 
        popoverTitle='Comments' triggers='mouseenter' [outsideClick]='true' container='body' placement='right'>
    </foreignObject>

    <ng-template #commentsTemplate>
        <span class='comment' *ngFor='let comment of getComments(textBox.id)'>
          {{comment}}
        </span>

        <input type='text' class='form-control comment-input' placeholder='Add comment...'>
        <button class='btn btn-secondary comment-submit'>Comment</button>
    </ng-template>
</g>
```

When angular-cli builds the application (don't show errors), browser shows only a blank page and the console shows the following error:

> Error: Template parse errors: Unexpected closing tag
>   ":svg:ng-template". It may happen when the tag has already been closed
>   by another tag. For more info see
>   https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have-implied-end-tags ("dd comment...'>
>               Comment
>             [ERROR ->]
>           
>          "): ng:///AppModule/ReadComponent.html@78:10

But I has set popover container the "body".

I've already tried use ng-container and put the ng-template tag inside another foreignObject, but console says that :svg:ng-template not exists...

I can't put ng-template inside the main foreignObject because I'm binding the content of it (I didn't show that bind to avoid misunderstanding).

Sorry for the confusing english.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. I did put a ng-container inside ng-template of the loop. So my ng-container calls a external ng-template, passing context.

```
<svg>
    <g *ngFor='let textBox of textBoxes'>
        <foreignObject [id]='textBox.name' [attr.x]='textBox.topLeftNode.x' [attr.y]='textBox.topLeftNode.y'
            [attr.width]='getWidth(textBox)' [attr.height]='getHeight(textBox)' [popover]='preCommentsTemplate' 
            popoverTitle='Comments' triggers='mouseenter' [outsideClick]='true' container='body' placement='right'>
        </foreignObject>

        <ng-template #preCommentsTemplate>
            <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet='commentsTemplate; context: textRectangle'></ng-container>
        </ng-template>
    </g>
</svg>

<ng-template #commentsTemplate let-id='id'>
    <span class='comment' *ngFor='let comment of getComments(id)'>
      {{comment}}
    </span>

    <input type='text' class='form-control comment-input' placeholder='Add comment...'>
    <button class='btn btn-secondary comment-submit'>Comment</button>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: You're a superstar! I was using ng-bootstrap but had a very similar issue attaching complex tooltips to SVG shapes.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to warn you that since angular 9 `<ng-template>` often gives issues when used inside an `<svg>` element. See [also](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14257).

I ended up replacing all of `<ng-template>` with `<g>` elements, which can also contain structural directives like `*ngIf` and `*ngFor`.